# Creating branches from two existing, independent directories

Tags: git

We haven't had any version control up until now. We have 2 version of our application, let's assume they're in `/var/www/demo` and `/var/www/production`. One of goals is to merge both of them, so I would like to create 2 branches: `demo` and `production` from existing files, and I have no idea how to do that.

I've managed already to create a repo and push all files from one of the environments to the remote bare repo - but how do I automatically add another one as a branch without opening and modifying files one by one?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to copy the last production sources to a separate folder and initialize this as a git repo

```
cp -av productionsources forgit
cd gorgit
git init .
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit production sources"
```

Now you can create a branch for your demo sources and check them in the same repository. Before this you should delete all sources, but keep the .git folder. Copy the demo sources to the repository and them and commit

```
git checkout -b demo
rm *.c ...
cp -av ../demosources/* .
git add .
git commit -m "initial commit demo sources"
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you created your repo with the files in `/var/www/production` and want to create a `demo` branch, the simplest way is to create the branch and copy the demo files in.

```
cd your_new_repo         
git checkout -b demo              # Start a new branch
rm -rf *                          # Wipe out production files (but not .git/)
cp -R /var/www/demo/* .           # Copy in all demo files
git add -A .                      # Add them to Git
git commit -m 'Import demo files' # Commit them
```

This commit will effectively be a diff between your old `production` and `demo` directories, as if you opened and modified each file, but with somewhat less typing. Because Git tracks content, files that are destroyed by the `rm -rf` but haven't changed in the demo files won't appear in the diff after they're copied back in. The `add -A` option tells Git to both add all files it hasn't seen yet and remove from the index any that have disappeared, which will take care of files that exist in production, but not in the demo.

If something surprises you and you need to start over, `git reset --hard origin/master` (or whatever branch you put your production files in) will get you back to a clean state.